# Redux state is read-only

Tags: react-native, redux, state

I am trying to pass the result of the button pressed to a Redux state. The user has a choice between "No" 'and "Yes"

I want to add it to the state and then navigate the user to the next screen. Below is how I am declaring the state.

```
    const [state, setState ] = useState ({
      isDisabled: true,
      showAnswer: false,
      uuid: '',
    })
    const [value, onChange] = useState('')
    const [codeValue, onCodeChange] = useState('')
    state = {
        animation: new Animated.Value(0),
      };
      const handleOnChange = (name, value) => {
        setState({
        ...state,
            [name] : value,
        });
        console.log([name],':',value)
    };
```

This is the button.

```
    <Button       
       title={"No"}
        style = {GettingToKnowYouStyle.choices}
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate ('Employment')}
       >
       No
     </Button>
```

I know I am doing a lot wrong here please help.

Comment: Nothing in your code would suggest you are using redux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

careful, you're mixing things up here! `useState` refers to the *component state*, not the *redux state*.

you need a *redux* state (aka `reducer`), at least one `action` to dispatch and something to handle side effects (I recommend either `rxjs` and `redux-observable` or `saga`).

the hook into `redux` then is called `useDispatch`, as [from the docs](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks).

I suggest the following: Dispatch action 1 with the answer, update the state. after successful state reduction dispatch action 2 handling the route change. try reading the docs ([basic tutorial](https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/basic-tutorial) is a good point to get started) and come back with detailed questions if you have some.

Answer (score 0):

You should use useDispatch() to change the redux state.